Xcode15 copied by Android Emulator build system recognizes ASAN flags but doesn't do anything
I am building Android Emulator (emu-33-dev branch) on Mac M2/M3, using this build script:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/emu-33-dev:external/qemu/android/rebuild.sh
In short, even if -fsanitize=address is added to all compile commands, it seems like the executable does not have ASAN. It never catches my intentional memory leaks, etc.
I would like to ask this question with a reduced example:
int main() {
  volatile int* buf = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buf = new int;
    *buf = i;
    sum += *buf;
  }
  return sum;
}

My understanding is that it does have memory leaks. I expect ASAN to report it. However, it doesn't. It does not, even with a simple example above, let alone the actual production code.
I think Android Emulator copies some of the commandline tools from Xcode. Thus, for example, this is the g++ executable I find in the compile_command.json file:
external/qemu/objs/toolchain/g++ 

Here's what --version with the compiler driver says:
$ /Users/me/workspace/emu-dev/external/qemu/objs/toolchain/g++ --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

This is how I compiled my example code:
cd ~/workspace/emu-dev/external/qemu
./objs/toolchain/g++ -g3 -O3 -o my.x -Wall --verbose -fsanitize=address my.cc 

Running ./my.x terminates normally with the return code saved in sum.
I suspected that I might not be linking the library correctly, searched Google for ldd equivalent, and found otool. Here's the output:
$ otool -L ./my.x
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.151.0)
    @rpath/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)

But if I did not have a library to load at runtime, why did my.x terminate even before loading the executable to the memory?
What should I check and/or fix to make this work so I can run ASAN for the production code built from Android Emulator source?

I don't think that Address Sanitizer detects memory leaks. It is not an "Allocation Sanitizer". Instead, try to read or write memory out of bounds, like in int* buf=new int; for(int i=0; i<10;i++) sum += *buf++;

Does LSAN (Leak Sanitizer) detect the memory leak?

Thank you, prapin and Eljay, for your help. I thought -fsanitize=address will find memory leaks as well; clang (14.0, Debian) and gcc do so on Linux. Both of them detected the errors from my program. However, on Mac, it looks like the issue is that the Leak Sanitizer is missing. --fsantize=leak was recognized on Linux but was not on Mac. At least, now I understood the problem.
